# Side effect of a lot printf?

Tags: c, performance, gcc

Greeting !!!

I have several c ap running in CentOS Linux compiled in gcc version 4.4.4  ,
using putty.exe in ssh connection to the server  ,
THREADLIB=POSIX  ,  because my ap use a lot of threads and I need to watch a lot of 
information , using  a lot of printf  to the screen for watching speed and information ,
while I can not focus on one item , I use "printScr" keyboard and paste it to MS Paint ,
that is quite easy to use !!

While I print too many information in like for loop , I feel that the speed of 
my ap is slower ever since , and it run faster if I take away those printf in for loop ..

My question is :Is "too many screen output" really affect the speed of ap  ?
and if it is true , except for reduce printf , what else I can do to not affect speed 
too much ?

Thanks for any information !!

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Printing out to the screen is an expensive operation, especially when your terminal doesn't buffer it when outputting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I/O is slow and the terminal tends to be an exceptionally slow I/O device. Redirecting your output to a file will likely help substantially. To illustrate consider the following times for a million iterations:

No printf:  0.008s 
To /dev/null:   0.182s 
To file:    0.22s  
To terminal:    2.513s

Comment: Thanks , so if I run my ap like ./ap.exe > /tmp/ap.txt , even I did not change my code , I still get better performance ? because I skip screen display and /tmp/ap.txt file has buffer , am I correct ?

Comment: That's what I would expect but as always, test it to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Logging to screen will cause a performance impact. Try to minimize the number of times printf is called, and write the output to file instead. That should help speed up your program somewhat.

[Link](http://rxwen.blogspot.com/2010/07/performance-impact-of-printf.html)

Answer (score 0):

Printing to file may gain you some speed (depending on your system configuration), although the best way would be to reduce the amount of information you log (keep in mind that input/output operations are always considered slow). Is it really important to print in every loop of your cycle? Can't you count, average or somehow summarize the information, and then print that summary at the end of the loop?